# Gmail API with WP SMTP Plugins Not Sending to Gsuite "groups"

Tags: wordpress, smtp, gmail-api

**When we use any SMTP plugins for WordPress with the Gmail API we are unable to receive any WP generated emails to our group email addresses sales@example.com or info@example.com such as product inquiries, order emails, or contact form emails.**

Without the SMTP set up all emails to the groups deliver fine and have for the past 3+ years.  When the smtp plugin is active and set up according to these help docs we recieve no WP generated emails.

We have tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/gmail-smtp/ as well as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

These are the associated help docs, respectively: https://wphowto.net/gmail-smtp-plugin-for-wordpress-1341, https://wpforms.com/how-to-securely-send-wordpress-emails-using-gmail-smtp/

```
2019-04-03 21:18:25 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
2019-04-03 21:18:25 Connection: opened
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c18sm9527617qkk.1 - gsmtp"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c18sm9527617qkk.1 - gsmtp
2019-04-03 21:18:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO dev.equusport.com
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2019-04-03 21:18:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2019-04-03 21:18:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO dev.equusport.com
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [67.205.36.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2019-04-03 21:18:25 Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
2019-04-03 21:18:25 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH
2019-04-03 21:18:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 closing connection c18sm9527617qkk.1 - gsmtp"
2019-04-03 21:18:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection c18sm9527617qkk.1 - gsmtp
2019-04-03 21:18:25 Connection: closed
```

The desired result is simply to be able to have WP send associated emails to our group emails and have them be delivered.  I checked the gsuite log and they aren't even showing so it looks like the Gmail API is intercepting them and never pushing them to our Gsuite group emails.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We focus on programming Q&A. You may get better answers on our sister site superuser.com

Comment: Hi @Simon.S.A. I tried to post to the other platform but it is marking my message (this exact same one) as spam and they don't have a gmail-api tag.  What do you suggest I do? Thanks!

Comment: This might be because automated checks are run between sites to prevent duplication of questions. I can only guess without further research. If so, you might be able to post a variant of this question, or delete this question and re-ask on superuser (after a delay to allow the automated checkers to forget about the deleted question). See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: This IS a programming problem and I would like to know the answer...